# Use output of numpy.argsort to sort in-place

Tags: numpy

I have two arrays, A and B.
I want to sort A and B with respect to A, so i do:

```
sort_order = numpy.argsort(A)
A = A[sort_order]
B = B[sort_order]
```

Problem is, A and B are both very very large, and thus the above has a tendency to result in an out-of-memory error. This is because after the last line has run, in memory are both the sorted and unsorted datasets, as the garbage collector hasn't gotten around to freeing the memory.

So how does one use the sort_order generated by argsort to sort an array in-place?

Comment: Use `a.sort()` to replace the first indexing step?

Comment: Sounds like you could use `np.take(A, sort_order, out=A)` and  `np.take(B, sort_order, out=B)`  instead. That'll reuse the memory occupied by `A` and `B` for the sorted arrays, instead of allocating new memory.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: oh, good point, it may do. However, I'm not certain if `A[sort_order]` makes a brand new array *first*, which *then* gets copied into `A`'s buffer. I'd have to go and do some checking.

Comment: @ajcr I'm almost sure it does. I find it difficult to picture a way of doing a permutation in-place correctly, since you are overwriting lots of elements you are going to need later. Sorting is another matter because you are sequentially flipping pairs.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: actually yes you're probably correct there - specifying `out`  as the same array might lead to strange results with `take`.

Comment: @ajcr: `take` seems to work fine for me even with overlap - perhaps it's making a copy under the hood, although I'm struggling to see where.

Comment: @ajcr it seems to get it right which kind of leads me to think it probably does make a copy somewhere.

Comment: You might be able to encourage the gc to free the memory with `A[...] = A[sort_order]`

Comment: I agree - `take` gets it right in my simple tests, although I don't yet see anywhere in [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2aabeafb97bea4e1bfa29d946fbf31e1104e7ae0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L30-L247) (for example) where overlap is detected and/or a temporary copy is made.

Comment: @Eric @ajcr Found it. It's the `clipmode` which defaults to `raise` which leads to an `ENSURE_COPY` flag being set. Change `clipmode` to something else and you will get wrong results.

Comment: Good find - in that case there's no obvious benefit to using `take` with `out` over something like `A[:] = A[sorted_array]` here.

Comment: "and you will get wrong results" - can you give an example? My results still seem ok

Comment: @Eric: if I do `A = np.array([1, 4, 2, 3, 5]; A2 = A.copy(); s = np.argsort(A)` then `np.take(A, s, out=A, mode='clip')` gives `array([1, 2, 3, 2, 5])` (note the duplicate 2) whereas `A2[:] = A2[s]` or `np.take(A2, s, out=A2)` is correct (this is in 1.11.3).

Comment: Do you think this might be considered a bug? Given the recent work that has gone into detecting whether ufunc operations involve overlapping memory (e.g. [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/8043)), would it make sense for checks to be extended to other functions too?

Comment: I think it's just that no one has gotten around to implementing it yet, since as  Paul Panzer mentioned it's not as simple as flipping pairs. You'd need to write an ipargsort function, that takes argsort's output and expresses it in the minimum number of flips to transform A to B. arr.sort could then have a mode to understand that notation. Using indices to sort an array is a great idea in a world with infinite memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in-place numpy array sorting according to given index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239802/in-place-numpy-array-sorting-according-to-given-index)