# Using the results of numpy.argsort to in place sort arrays

Tags: python, numpy

In place rearrange like described below is not a good goal because, as hpaulj pointed out, "in-place writes will step on each other, overwriting some of your data". I'll leave this up though incase anyone else gets tunnel vision and doesn't consider this like I did.

I am aware of [numpy.ndarray.sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort) to in place sort numpy arrays. However, what if I want to sort 2 or more arrays with the same sort indices as the first? I know that we can use numpy.argsort() to get the sort indices and do:

```
sortInd = np.argsort(X)
X = X[sortInd]
Y = Y[sortInd]
```

However, it is my understanding that this will temporally create a copy of the arrays X and Y (maybe I'm wrong here). So how can I do in place sort using a list of sort indices? Something like:

```
 sortInd = np.argsort(X)
 X.rearrange(sortInd)
 Y.rearrange(sortInd)
```

Comment: It doesn't sound unreasonable, but I'm not sure numpy provides the function. A very similar question was asked here, without answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748439/use-output-of-numpy-argsort-to-sort-in-place

Comment: Actually, I think this question has the answer you need, so I'm voting to close this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239802/in-place-numpy-array-sorting-according-to-given-index

Comment: Thank you, I looked before posting the question but must of missed that one.

Comment: Even though I answered one of the links, I question whether in-place is a reasonable goal.  Regardless of method, every element of `X` will have to be written to a new location (whether in the same data buffer or new one).  So in-place can't save time. 
 And if it's done without buffering, there's a chance that in-place writes will step on each other, messing up your data.

Comment: I think you're correct. Well that explains why they don't have it implemented.