# Is it possible to shuffle a numpy array in place by a defined index list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Re-ordering a numpy array with a given list of indexes, like the following:

```
arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
idx = [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
arr[idx]
```

will result in making a copy of the whole array.

However, the numpy.shuffle() method works in place:

```
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

will not make a copy of the array and shuffle it IN PLACE.

So it seems like there should be a way of shuffling an array in place, but with a pre-ordered list of indexes? How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in-place numpy array sorting according to given index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239802/in-place-numpy-array-sorting-according-to-given-index)

Comment: `arr[:] = are[idx]`?

Comment: Are you more concerned about speed or memory use?  Or both?

Comment: @hpaulj definitely memory use. I have an array that is using pretty much all of my available memory which I need to modify, but can;t afford to make a copy.

Comment: `ufunc` like `np.add` have an `at` method that bypasses temporary buffering (that occurs with `+=`).  But I don't think there's anything equivalent that moves values.  @juanpa.arrivillaga's suggestion is going to make a temporary copy.

Comment: that is correct, solutions proposed by juanpa.arrivillaga and Dinari make temporary copies.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of duplicating my previous answer, I'll try to illustrate the problem with doing an in-place shuffle without any sort of copy.

Your sample:

```
In [196]: arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
     ...: idx = [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
```

The straightforward approach:

```
In [197]: arr[idx]
Out[197]: array([20, 10, 40, 50, 30])
```

Effectively it is doing:

```
In [198]: [arr[1],arr[0],arr[3],arr[4],arr[2]]
Out[198]: [20, 10, 40, 50, 30]
```

A naive iterative approach:

```
In [199]: for i,v in enumerate(idx):
     ...:     arr[i] = arr[v]
     ...: 
In [200]: arr
Out[200]: array([20, 20, 40, 50, 40])
```

Oops - that has stepped on values.  `arr[1]` has been copied to [0]. That is then copied [1].  The 10 and 30 have been lost.

The iterative solution requires a copy:

```
In [201]: arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
     ...: idx = [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
In [202]: arr1 = arr.copy()
     ...: for i,v in enumerate(idx):
     ...:     arr[i] = arr1[v]
     ...: 
In [203]: arr
Out[203]: array([20, 10, 40, 50, 30])
```

In [205]: arr[idx]=arr
In [206]: arr
Out[206]: array([10, 10, 30, 30, 30])

It may be possible to come up with an indexing that avoids this, but it would take some thought.  I suspect old classical computer science (Knuth?) worked this out, since old computers has much smaller RAM, and often depended on values read serially from tape.

Other indexing attempts:

```
In [205]: arr[idx]=arr
In [206]: arr
Out[206]: array([10, 10, 30, 30, 30])
In [207]: arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
     ...: idx = [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
In [208]: arr[idx]=arr.copy()
In [209]: arr
Out[209]: array([20, 10, 50, 30, 40])
```

Comment: This is a good illustration of the issue, why we need a copy for any "naive" approach, as all these proposed solution require a copying step and are not in place right?

Comment: by the way, do you understand how the method numpy.random.shuffle() avoids this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure `shuffle` avoids a copy; it isn't faster than `arr[idx]`.  SInce there are in-place sorting methods, there may be a true in-place shuffle, but I never formally studied these matters.

Comment: @hirschme probably because it's not implemented in Python

Comment: Based on a cursory reading of the `cython` code inhttps://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/5cae51e794d69dd553104099305e9f92db237c53/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx, I think `shuffle` is doing a bunch of `item` (array element or subarray) swaps.  That just requires an `item` sized temporary buffer.  Bubble sort is an in-place sort that uses exchanges.